# Reinitialize flask extensions

Tags: flask, flask-mongoengine

I am using flask. I have a few routes defined that are expensive as they need to access a database and do lengthy computations. The database connectivity is relying on the Flask-Mongoengine extension which relies on PyMongo which is not threadsafe.

Hence my thoughts are as follows:

```
@blueprint.route("/refresh/data", methods=['GET'])
def refresh_data():
    cache.clear()

    with Pool(4) as p:
        print(p.map(func=f, iterable=["recently", "mtd", "ytd", "sector"]))
```

Get a small pool and call the function f. The function f is based on

```
def f(name):
    print(current_app.extensions)
    print(current_app.config)

    current_app.extensions["mongoengine"] = MongoEngine(app=current_app)
    print(current_app.extensions)

    get(address="reports/{path}/json".format(path=name))
    get(address="reports/{path}/html".format(path=name))
    return name
```

The problem here is that one cannot init_app the MongoEngine again. In fact, extensions can be initialize only once but what happens it the extensions is needed on multiple threads and is not threadsafe?

Comment: just curious, why not rely on celery or any task qeues apps to handle asynchronously long-running jobs ?

Comment: that's a can I try to keep closed for now